# Convert an object to an especific type c#

Tags: c#, azure, web, azure-cosmosdb

I'm doing a web application in c# in which I consult the data that is in a CosmoDB that I have in Azure. This cosmoDB has documents that are Jsons of some data structures that I have defined as models in my web application. The problem is that when making the query to have different types of structures in the database I must do it as object type to later convert it into a specific type and display it on the screen in an html code. Actually the code I have is a code that gives you an Azure tutorial modified according to my application.

The code is the following:

```
namespace todo
{
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Optimization;
 using System.Web.Routing;
 using System.Collections;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Linq;

 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        DocumentDBRepository<Object>.Initialize();
    }
  }
}
```

Then Home controller makes:

```
    [ActionName("ECCE")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ECCEAsync(string id)
    {
        var items = await DocumentDBRepository<Object>.GetItemsAsync(id);
        return View((ECCE_SupportData)items);
    }
```

Where the class DocumentDBRepository makes:

```
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(string collectionId)
    {
        List<T> results = new List<T>();

        try
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return results;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

To later pass the list of objects to the html to see them on the screen:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/TableFilter/tablefilter.js"></script>

@model IEnumerable<todo.Models.ECCE.ECCE_SupportData>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Data";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ECCE Data</h2>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <table class="table" id="ECCETable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_CnfStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_ComsStatus.ComStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_ComsStatus.UltimoError)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_Status.AppVersion.IdApp)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_Status.AppVersion.ReqVersion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_Status.AppVersion.SwVersion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_Status.AppStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ECCE_UvStatus.NumUVs)
            </th>
            
    </table>
```

The problem is that in the HomeController when I try to convert the Object to my data structure ECCE_SuportData gives me an error: You can't convert an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.Object]' to the type 'todo.Models. ECCE.ECCE_SupportData '

Does anyone know how I can convert the object to this data structure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post here in English. If you don't speak English: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Write in english

Comment: okay I will write it right now

Comment: in  the method `EcceAsync`, use the type `todo.Models.ECCE.ECCE_SupportData` as the generic parameter like this: `var items = await DocumentDBRepository<ECCE.ECCE_SupportData>.GetItemsAsync(id);`

Comment: If I do that I'm not obtaining any data because I'm inicializing the DocumentDBRepository to <Object> : DocumentDBRepository<Object>.Initialize();

Comment: But you should initialize it with the specific type as well.

Comment: Okay so I should do DocumentDBRepository<ECCE_SupportData>.Initialize(); but if I have to obtain another type of data with that class how can I do it?

Comment: Not sure what azure tutorial you have used as a source but it seems the Initialize() method can be called just once, no matter the generic argument. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-dotnet-todo-app/blob/master/src/DocumentDBRepository.cs#L74. So if you need other types just use `await DocumentDBRepository<MyOtherType>.GetItemsAsync(id)`

Comment: Okay I will try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that the way you are implementing the repository is fundamentally wrong. I know you are using the Azure sample but these samples are not necessarily the best way to go about implementing it. A static repository implementation would never work in a real life scenario where you have multiple types of documents you need to work with.

What you need to do is create an instance of this repository per type of object you need to operate against. This would mean, removing the `static` keywords and registering the repository instance as a singleton for your application's lifetime.

You can find a (kinda outdated but) decent implementation of what you need to do [here](https://github.com/Crokus/cosmosdb-repo).

Also, for up to date CosmosDB related samples I would highly recommend you use the [official CosmosDB .NET Github repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples). They have a folder full of samples for pretty much anything.

If however you want to go for a more ORM-like implementation you should also take a look at [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut).

With that all your code would become this:

```
var items = await cosmoStore.Query().ToListAsync;
```

The choice is completely up to you and what fits best for your requirements.

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Cosmonaut*